# How to use Reflection GetMethods on protected readonly method

Tags: c#, .net

I have several protected readonly methods in a class that I need to retrieve so I can get the custom attributes.  I am comfortable getting the custom attributes but how do I get the methods?  This is the boiled down class:

```
public class TheParser
{
    [myAttribute("test")]
    protected readonly Parser<String> MyKeyWord;
}
```

And to get the methods I have tried many combinations using different BindingFlags but obviously I haven't found the right combination. Here is one attempt:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(TheParser).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a method.. its a field.

Use `GetFields` with `NonPublic` and `Instance`:

```
var fields = typeof(TheParser)
                 .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (var field in fields)
    Console.WriteLine(field.Name); // prints "MyKeyWord"
```